# Remove Overlay Background in camera view

Tags: android, layout, android-camera, android-linearlayout, surfaceview

What im Trying to Do is create a camera preview in surfaceview and add buttons on top of it.

Im getting a camera preview but unfortunately the `Linearlayout` has a ugly white background.

How can it be transparent ?

I even tried `#00ffffff` but didnt work

```
<FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/surfaceView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></SurfaceView>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the buttons, you need to add the following attribute.

```
android:background="@null"
```